# Nested do until works only 1 time

Tags: excel, vba

There shall be total 125 outputs, but only 5 outputs are  coming because only inner most loop (c loop) runs for 5 times. Loop a & b are not running, i am not sure why. I tried solving it similarly with "for....next" also, it was giving 45 outputs.

requesting for your kind help. sorry for bad english.

```
Sub ColourCheck2()

Dim a, b, c As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

a = 1
b = 6
c = 11

Do Until a > 5
    Do Until b > 10
        Do Until c > 15
            Sheet2.Cells(b + c, a).Value = a & " " & b & " " & c
            Sheet2.Cells(b + c, a).Interior.Color = RGB(a, b, c)
            c = c + 1
        Loop
    b = b + 1
    Loop
    a = a + 1
Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

---

Results

---

Column A Column B Column C
1 6 11  2 6 11  3 6 11
1 6 12  2 6 12  3 6 12
1 6 13  2 6 13  3 6 13
1 6 14  2 6 14  3 6 14
1 6 15  2 6 15  3 6 15
1 7 11  2 7 11  3 7 11
1 7 12  2 7 12  3 7 12
1 7 13  2 7 13  3 7 13
1 7 14  2 7 14  3 7 14
1 7 15  2 7 15  3 7 15
1 8 11  2 8 11  3 8 11
1 8 12  2 8 12  3 8 12
1 8 13  2 8 13  3 8 13
1 8 14  2 8 14  3 8 14
1 8 15  2 8 15  3 8 15
and so on down below also..

similarly for column D & E also

Comment: You need to reset b and c before each corresponding loop. In addition, since you add b and c to get cell addresses, some cells will be overwritten.

Comment: yes i couldn't understand that earlier thanks a lot :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go

```
Sub ColourCheck2()

    Dim a As Long, b As Long, c As Long, d As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    a = 1
    b = 6
    c = 11
    d = 0

    Do Until a > 5
        d = 0
        b = 6
        Do Until b > 10
            c = 11
            Do Until c > 15
                Sheet2.Cells(b + (d * 4) + c, a).Value = a & " " & b & " " & c
                Sheet2.Cells(b + (d * 4) + c, a).Interior.Color = vbYellow ' RGB(a, b, c)
                c = c + 1

            Loop
            d = d + 1
            b = b + 1
        Loop
        a = a + 1
    Loop

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot santosh bhai for the code. it was working fine but when i tried for larger number of loops it was not working properly, I am sorry I cant explain how.. anyway I solved it by another method. I will just paste the code for someones reference.

Comment: @sarveshprasad Ok bhai. Please click on checkmark next to answer if this is helpful

Comment: For a = 1 To 5
b = Empty
c = Empty
    For b = 1 To 5
    c = Empty
    k = Sheet2.Cells(32000, a).End(xlUp).Row
        For c = 1 To 5
            Sheet2.Cells(c + k, a).Value = a & " " & b & " " & c
            'Sheet1.Cells(c + k, a).Font.Color = RGB(a * 10, b * 10, c * 10)
            Sheet2.Cells(c + k, a).Interior.Color = RGB(a, b, c)
        Next c
    Next b
Next a

Answer (score 1):

Or just use for/next loops:

```
For a = 1 to 5
    For b = 6 to 10
        For c = 11 to 15
            Sheet2.Cells(b + c, a).Value = a & " " & b & " " & c
            Sheet2.Cells(b + c, a).Interior.Color = RGB(a, b, c)
        Next c
    Next b
Next a
```

Comment: thanks walleye for your time. this is what i initially tried before trying do until. anyway i solved it thanks.